# Issue installing phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When attempting to install **phpmyadmin** using yum install phpmyadmin, I get an error that reads:

```
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.22-1.el6.remi
Installed: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (@base)
php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
```

Since I had phpmyadmin running perfectly fine just a few hours ago, I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: updating my php to 5.4.22 gets me this error:

```
Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: CentOS 6 I need more characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `php-common` package. Here is a download link for the required `php-common` package in your case.

http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/php-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

Comment: That throws an error: error: Failed dependencies:
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.22-1.el6.remi is needed by php-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64
        php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.22-1.el6.remi is needed by php-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64

Comment: in your terminal type `which php` to make sure your running using your old version of php

Comment: which php tells me /usr/bin/php but I don't understand what that means. You mentioned old version of php, so I tried removing php54w and installing php5.3.3 back, same error.

Answer (score -1):

The version of the library php-mcrypt is higher than the php version you have installed. Upgrade your php

Comment: phpmyadmin states it requires 5.2, but never the less i upgraded to 5.4.22 and receive a new error. 
   Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: Do you need both versions on your system?

Comment: No, I've removed php5.3.3 as far as I know, but it's still showing up for some reason.